# Изменение значений атрибутов name в input

Tags: c#

На aspx странице есть форма:

```html
<form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
    <input name="shopId" value="00000" type="hidden" required/>
    <input name="scid" value="00000" type="hidden" required/>
    <input runat="server" id="inpOrderNumber" name="orderNumber" value="0" type="hidden" required/>
    <input runat="server" id="inpCustNumber" type="hidden" required name="customerNumber" value="" size="64"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Оплатить">
</form>
```

когда страница открывается, то значения атрибутов name в инпутах изменяются на значения которые указаны в id, как это побороть? Это происходит после добавления runat="server", но он нужен для того чтобы заполнять инпуты из cs кода.

Comment: В случаях "конфликтов" используются свойства контрола ClientID и UniqueID, которые однозначно говорят какой id и какой name у сгенерированого контрола. Читайте http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx матчасть. Ответ на вопрос - несколько листиков А4... но всётаки хорошо бы, правда, более подробно описать в чём ваша проблема. Данный пример не отражает в чём проблема, а вопрос относится к разряду "основы ASP".

Comment: А, да *заполнять инпуты из cs кода* Всё просто, открыли сs и пишем  `inpOrderNumber.Text="Заполнено";` в... допустим Page_Load методе.

Comment: Как заполнять значениями инпуты мне понятно, такой вопрос я не задавал. Вопрос был другой - почему значения в name изменяются на значения которые в id?

Comment: Читайте основы ASP, это его особенность. Так задумано.